# How to use input element through the specified class in woocommerce?

Tags: html, css, class, web, input

I am trying to use the ***input[type=number]*** Quantity number through a class in woo-commerce beside the **add to cart** button but it's not working, I think a simple thing is missing here.

```
input[type=number].input-text.qty.text {
    padding: 0.4em !important;
    width: 9em !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: what's not working? the styling you are trying to apply?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti yes the styling